# Https Spring MVC controller call with Android

Tags: java, android, spring, mongodb, cordova

I have a web applcation which is build in Spring MVC and MongoDB, what I want to make an app of Android (I am new in Andriod).

I am thinking to reuse that Spring Restful Web Services in Android app, and just make the frontend of Android app.

i have read about Spring Android but it's not what i want, i want to reuse the existing web services, isn't it java all about platform independent?

I have gone through many articles but they don't clear my confusion.

i have read about phonegap to convert html in an app, but i also want to synchronize the contacts in phone through android app which i believe is only possible with Android.

Comment: The idea of Spring for Android is for consuming web services; which part of it that isn't suit your need?

Comment: Spring for Android is differnet framework and need to code web services like it. if i am wrong correct me @cipley

Comment: Uuum, no.....basically Spring for Android is used to consume already existing REST web services. There is absolutely no need to rewrite your web services; Spring for Android provides a (more convenient) way to consume web services.

Comment: I am using Spring for Android in conjunction with AndroidAnnotations to make it even easier. see here: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API